# How the variables work on the command Add on MIPS

Tags: mips

i have a task which i cannot understand
There are 2 Mips codes which i have to write in C

a)

1.Add f,g,h

b)

1. Addi f,f,1
2. Add f,g,h

My question is on (b) Does this mean that f = (f+1) + (g+h) or f = g + h
I don't understand if the first line is overwriten by the second which makes the codes on (a) and (b) the same

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`addi f, f, 1` means `f = f + 1`, and `add f, g, h` means `f = g + h`.

The second instruction will overwrite the value of `f` produced in the first instruction, so the first instruction has no net effect (other than consuming time and energy) unless the symbol `f` has been defined to be the same register as `g` or `h`.

Comment: I like to think of `addi f,g,h` as "add h to g and store the result in f."